# How to skip 'for' loop when dealing with numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

>>> x
array([[   1,   57],
       [   2,   21],
       [   4,   34],
       ...,
       [3348,   29],
       [3350,   23],
       [3353,   11]])

>>> x.shape
(1310, 2)


>>> pic           # greyscale image

array([[223, 222, 225, ..., 217, 219, 214],
       [224, 222, 219, ..., 220, 219, 216],
       [223, 224, 220, ..., 219, 215, 213],
       ...,
       [228, 226, 231, ..., 224, 228, 229],
       [229, 227, 227, ..., 216, 225, 227],
       [226, 228, 225, ..., 218, 225, 230]], dtype=uint8)

pic = np.stack((pic,pic,pic), axis=2)

>>> pic.shape
(2208, 2752, 3)

>>>labels.shape
(2208, 2752)


color = [0, 0, 255]

for i in x:
    B=np.full((i[1],3), color).astype('int')
    pic[labels==i[0]]=B
```

It colors all the pixels in grayscale image `(pic)` with blue `(rgb 0,0,255)`, which satisfy the condition `pic[labels==i[0]]`. Now, this is very slow because of the 'for' loop used `(for i in x)`.

> Is there any efficient 'Numpy way', which won't include for loop, and
>   would, therefore, be much faster. Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Does this `pic[labels==i[0]]=B` even work? I mean `pic` is a 1-channel image, while `B` is 3-channel. Can you do `imshow()` after your operation?

Comment: Can you comment/explain your code a bit more? Where/how is your `labels` array created? Does `labels==i[0]` work? Looking at the shape of `labels` and `i`, I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: You can almost always avoid loops in NumPy but it's very hard to help you here. Can you explain what you're trying to do, and show us what `labels` looks like? I don't see how the last line can possibly work, because `B` is a 2D array and you're trying to change a single element of another 2D array with it. It's so much easier if you can take the time to make a piece of code that actually runs, with toy arrays that represent your problem. Otherwise you're just asking too much of the community.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry I didn't clarify the problem more at the first place.. I'm working on greyscale images of some alloys microstructures taken with optical microscope, etc. My goal is to analyse the amount (%) of areas with given threshold (pixel count), as well as the number, size, etc. of these segments. For last I use:   from skimage import measure, morphology, which finds these segments and each segment has unique  integer in labels matrix, which has same shape as pic. I can do all, except coloring those segments on original image - without for loop..

Comment: So, each item in x is related to one segment, call it i, where i[0] is its unique 'serial' number, whereas i[1] is its area (number of pixels) . Toy code:
x = np.array([[1,3], [2,5], [6,2]] )  ;  labels=np.array([[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,2,2],[0,0,0,2,0],[6,6,0,0,0]]) ; pic = np.array([[223, 222, 225, 224, 227],[222, 224, 218, 220, 221],[216, 221, 219, 223, 225],[228, 226, 231, 224, 228],[226, 228, 225, 218, 225]]). For pic I forgot to convert it to 3-channel greyscale, of course:  pic=np.stack((pic,pic,pic), axis=2). It works fine, but I'd really like to avoid that for loop :)